# How customize Angular/Asp.NetCore/IdentityServer Login Template of visual studio?

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, authentication, redirect, identityserver4

I created a .net core Webapplication with Angular template in Visual Studio 2019. 
To modify the default Login UI, I used the Scaffold Identity in ASP.NET Core projects:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/scaffold-identity?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio

I generated the Login Page with the following method:

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(string returnUrl = null)
    {
        returnUrl = returnUrl ?? Url.Content("~/");

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // This doesn't count login failures towards account lockout
            // To enable password failures to trigger account lockout, set lockoutOnFailure: true
            var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(Input.Email, Input.Password, Input.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: false);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                _logger.LogInformation("User logged in.");
                return LocalRedirect(returnUrl);
            }
            if (result.RequiresTwoFactor)
            {
                return RedirectToPage("./LoginWith2fa", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = Input.RememberMe });
            }
            if (result.IsLockedOut)
            {
                _logger.LogWarning("User account locked out.");
                return RedirectToPage("./Lockout");
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Invalid login attempt.");
                return Page();
            }
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return Page();
    }
```

I changed the Login UI successfully. 
By Login the _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync returned True.
But the redirect functionality doesn´t work.
The ReturnUrl = ""

**How can I configure the redirect URL = http://localhost:4200 = Angular client url (as origin) ?**

Note: I start Angular Project and debug it with visual studio code and the API (Asp.net core) run seperated in Visual Studio (Not like the Angular template in VS).

Angular side configuration:

```js
let applicationPaths: ApplicationPathsType = {
  DefaultLoginRedirectPath: location.origin + '/',
  ApiAuthorizationClientConfigurationUrl: `https://localhost:44326/_configuration/${ApplicationName}`,
  Login: `authentication/${LoginActions.Login}`,
  LoginFailed: `authentication/${LoginActions.LoginFailed}`,
  LoginCallback: `authentication/${LoginActions.LoginCallback}`,
  Register: `authentication/${LoginActions.Register}`,
  Profile: `authentication/${LoginActions.Profile}`,
  LogOut: `authentication/${LogoutActions.Logout}`,
  LoggedOut: `authentication/${LogoutActions.LoggedOut}`,
  LogOutCallback: `authentication/${LogoutActions.LogoutCallback}`,
  LoginPathComponents: [],
  LoginFailedPathComponents: [],
  LoginCallbackPathComponents: [],
  RegisterPathComponents: [],
  ProfilePathComponents: [],
  LogOutPathComponents: [],
  LoggedOutPathComponents: [],
  LogOutCallbackPathComponents: [],
  IdentityRegisterPath: '/Identity/Account/Register',
  IdentityManagePath: '/Identity/Account/Manage'
};
```

Asp.Net core Startup:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

        services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            options.AddDefaultPolicy(
                builder =>
                {
                    builder.AllowAnyOrigin();
                    builder.AllowAnyMethod();
                    builder.AllowAnyOrigin();
                    builder.AllowAnyHeader();
                });
        });

        // configure identity
        services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();

        services.AddIdentityServer()
        .AddApiAuthorization<ApplicationUser, ApplicationDbContext>();

        services.AddAuthentication()
            .AddIdentityServerJwt();

        services.AddControllersWithViews()
        .AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
           options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver()
       );

        services.AddRazorPages();
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, IApiVersionDescriptionProvider provider)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            //app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
        }
        app.UseCors();
        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseSwagger();
        app.UseSwaggerUI(
            options =>
            {
                // build a swagger endpoint for each discovered API version
                foreach (var description in provider.ApiVersionDescriptions)
                {
                    options.SwaggerEndpoint($"/swagger/{description.GroupName}/swagger.json", description.GroupName.ToUpperInvariant());
                }
            });

        app.UseRouting();
        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseIdentityServer();
        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            endpoints.MapRazorPages();
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed the configuration in appsettings and now it work:

```
   "IdentityServer": {
    "Clients": {
      "BauDrApi": {
        "Profile": "SPA",
        "RedirectUri": "http://localhost:4200/authentication/login-callback",
        "logoutUri": "http://localhost:4200/authentication/logout-callback"
      }
    },
    "Key": {
      "Type": "Development"
    }
  },
```